# Undefined index in codeigniter mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using the following mysql query inside a codeigniter model:

```
$query = 'SELECT t.*, p.id as project_id, p.name as project_name, p.archive as project_archive
FROM project p
JOIN user_project up ON p.id = up.project AND up.user = '.$user.'
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tmp.* FROM
(SELECT *, IF( @prev <> project_id, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS rank, @prev := project_id
FROM task t
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r 
WHERE user_id = '.$user.' AND status < 3
ORDER BY t.project_id) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.rank <= 1) AS t ON p.id = t.project_id
ORDER BY p.id desc, t.status desc';

    $get = $this->db->query($query);

    if($get->num_rows > 0)
        return $get->result_array();

    return array();
```

This works fine but I would now like to retrieve an additional column from the same table as id and name. The column name is 'archive' and I tried adding

```
p.archive as project_archive
```

to the end of the first line but it is giving me a 'Undefined index: project_archive' error when I try and use this variable in the view. Just to ensure that I have everything right in the database I changed the first line to

```
$query = 'SELECT t.*, p.id as project_id, p.archive as project_name
```

and as expected the archive value was printed out as the project_name. So why can't I add the additional p.archive as project_archive???? My controller and view code are below

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->title = 'Dashboard';
    $this->menu = 'users|new_project';

    //Load models
    $this->load->model('project_model');
    $this->load->model('task_model');

    // Load tasks
    $data['tasks'] = $this->task_model->get_user_tasks($this->session->userdata('user'));

    $data['page_title']  = "Dashboard";
    $data['status_arr'] = $this->task_model->get_status_array();

    // Load View
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
}
```

In the view I am calling the following:

```
$tasks['project_archive'] <!-- undefined index error -->
$task['project_id'] <!-- working as expected -->
$task['project_name'] <!-- working as expected -->
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query is returning correctly with the `project_archive` value? I would try a `print_r` or `var_dump` of the data it's returning if you don't have access to run the query in phpMyAdmin or something similar. Also I noticed that in the view the first line is using the `tasks` array, but the other two are using the `task` array. With your controller code, I would think the bottom two wouldn't work - unless you didn't include something.

Comment: Good idea on the print_r I will try this. The tasks vs task is because I didn't include the for each loop in my posted code that uses tasks as task. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps. Turns out the reason the index was undefined was that the code needed to be in the foreach loop to give a value rather than calling outside the foreach loop and getting an array.